# Converting ASCII code with accents to plain text

Tags: encryption, character, ascii, diacritics

I have got some files from game I want to support by creating extra content. Problem is, that these files are not readable for me. They contains a lot of accent symbols and ASCII control characters (like  NUL or SOH, more info here: http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html). Below I've linked printscreen of example file. The printscreen is done in Notepad++, but it looks almost the same in all my text editors. Notepad++ found ASCII file format. I've tried to convert it with Notepad++ convert functions, but there was no readable effect.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ii7ndc6i4zgqo0h/shot_140321_193103.png

This file is created and editable by in-game editor. The game is able to read from this file, so I'm sure that this file is decryptable. Is there any way to convert it to plain text? If so, I would be able to create tool for this game, to generate those files automatically.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What makes you think the file is encrypted? It's most probably just a simple binary file format.

Comment: It would be wise to name the title of the game. With that information there MIGHT be a solution but without it there is no way of knowing the format of the file.

Comment: @EdvardFagerholm, maybe encryption is not the best word, sure. I've never dealt with it so far, my experience with such problems is little. This binary file may be just compiled object. I'm only trying to figure out if is it convertable to plain text, readable for me.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen, I don't think so, but of course, I can mention about game title. This file is a player profile from Deluxe Ski Jump game.

Comment: @BartHenry: I know so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the precise specification of the format in order to do any form of conversion into a format that is human readable. For example if you have a configuration file, which let's you store any combination of 8 different settings. In this case the binary file could be just a single byte, since you can let each bit in the byte denote whether or not the corresponding setting is turned on or off.

Now how would you convert this into a readable text form? The only way to do this is to figure out exactly what each bit in the byte means. Unless it's documented somewhere, you really have no choice except to edit the bits and see how the program behavior changes and try to deduce the format.

When dealing with a more complicated file that saves more complicated information as well as information that is internal to the software and never directly exposed to the user, this gets incredibly hard. Without documentation you're essentially left with the choice of making random edits to the file + reverse engineering the code, i.e. you take the machine code disassemble it and try to figure out what the program does.

In this particular case a player profile probably won't contain that much information, so you can just open the file in a hex editor and do the following:

1. Change some bit somewhere
2. Start the game and load the player
3. See what changed in the profile or if loading failed

Doing this you can try to deduce what each byte in the file represents.